# Issue with finding place name using geocoder

Tags: android

```
    lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0,0, this);

    Location location=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
if(location!=null)
    onLocationChanged(location);


    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        try {
        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude(), 2); // <10>
        for (Address address : addresses) {
        tv.setText(address.getAddressLine(0));
        }


}catch(Exception e){

}
```

This is my sample code. I created a class extending Locationlistener, I implemnetd the other abstract classes also. I was able to get the city name using this code. Now its not working.

Is there any mistake in this code?

Comment: What isn't working? error? stacktrace?

Comment: I am getting null pointer err. I dont know y I m not getting the lat and long also.

Comment: if i m giving double lat= location.getLatitude(); and tring to print it then

Comment: I m not getting lat and long. I m using a cell to test these. Some times after getting the lat and long, The place name is not getting listed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this....may be helpful

```
String add1 = "";
Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());

geoLatitude = p.getLatitudeE6()/1E6;
geoLongitude = p.getLongitudeE6()/1E6;

try {
    List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(p.getLatitudeE6()/1E6, p.getLongitudeE6()/1E6, 1);

    if(addresses.size() > 0 ) {
        for(int i=0; i<addresses.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
            add1 += addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(i) + "\n";
        }               
    }
}catch(IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}
```